# Syncing boolean with property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

How can I sync a property that has a string value with a boolean? 
I want to write something like this working prop sync:

```
:md-active.sync="menuIsVisible"
```

but with this property instead, that has a string value:

```
md-permanent="full"
```

and sync it with a boolean, like this somehow:

```
:md-permanent="full".sync="menuIsVisible"
```

I'm new at Vue, so please be gentle!

Comment: Am I right to say that you want to set `md-permanent` to 'full' when `menuIsVisible` is true? Could you try something like this: `:md-active.sync="menuIsVisible" :md-permanent="menuIsVisible ? 'full' : null"`

Comment: @SteGriffiths Yes exactly!! Thank you!